Unable to save pyspark sql dataframe
I have been trying to save a pyspark dataframe, but I keep getting py4Java error
data=ukb_df_data("test/bulk_strings.tsv")
data.createOrReplaceTempView("synthetic_biobank1")
data.write.saveAsTable("synthetic_biobank1")

This code runs and creates the directory, but there is no data in the directory in which I installed the winutils.exe.
D:\hadoop\bin
the error code right now is
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[8], line 3
      1 data=ukb_df_data("test/bulk_strings.tsv")
      2 data.createOrReplaceTempView("synthetic_biobank1")
----> 3 data.write.saveAsTable("synthetic_biobank1")

File c:\Users\kunal\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py:1521, in DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable(self, name, format, mode, partitionBy, **options)
   1519 if format is not None:
   1520     self.format(format)
-> 1521 self._jwrite.saveAsTable(name)

File c:\Users\kunal\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py:1322, in JavaMember.__call__(self, *args)
   1316 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\
   1317     self.command_header +\
   1318     args_command +\
   1319     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1321 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1322 return_value = get_return_value(
   1323     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1325 for temp_arg in temp_args:
   1326     if hasattr(temp_arg, "_detach"):

File c:\Users\kunal\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\errors\exceptions\captured.py:169, in capture_sql_exception.<locals>.deco(*a, **kw)
    167 def deco(*a: Any, **kw: Any) -> Any:
    168     try:
--> 169         return f(*a, **kw)
    170     except Py4JJavaError as e:
    171         converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

File c:\Users\kunal\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py:326, in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324 value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325 if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326     raise Py4JJavaError(
    327         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328         format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329 else:
    330     raise Py4JError(
    331         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
    332         format(target_id, ".", name, value))

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o260.saveAsTable.
: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:793)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:1249)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.list(FileUtil.java:1454)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.listStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1972)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:2014)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.listStatus(ChecksumFileSystem.java:761)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1972)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:2014)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.getAllCommittedTaskPaths(FileOutputCommitter.java:334)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJobInternal(FileOutputCommitter.java:404)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJob(FileOutputCommitter.java:377)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputCommitter.commitJob(ParquetOutputCommitter.java:48)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.commitJob(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$writeAndCommit$3(FileFormatWriter.scala:275)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$$Lambda$3593/912476963.apply$mcV$sp(Unknown Source)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.timeTakenMs(Utils.scala:552)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.writeAndCommit(FileFormatWriter.scala:275)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeWrite(FileFormatWriter.scala:304)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:190)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:190)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(QueryExecution.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1$$Lambda$2956/234705354.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$$Lambda$1704/1092957558.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$$Lambda$1691/94602884.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:900)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:461)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$Lambda$1291/905565329.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(origin.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:461)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:437)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertCommandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:142)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.writeAndRead(DataSource.scala:511)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.CreateDataSourceTableAsSelectCommand.saveDataIntoTable(createDataSourceTables.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.CreateDataSourceTableAsSelectCommand.run(createDataSourceTables.scala:183)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(QueryExecution.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1$$Lambda$2956/234705354.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$$Lambda$1704/1092957558.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$$Lambda$1691/94602884.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:900)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:461)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$Lambda$1291/905565329.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(origin.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:461)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:437)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertCommandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:142)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:859)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.createTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:700)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:678)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:571)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

The errorcode keeps changing by tweaks but I am unable to save. I don't know what I am doing wrong. my pyspark version is 3.5.1.
I was expecting to save the table in a directory as csv / parquet file for further use, But only the folders are created no csv is saved.

can you post the full traceback? there might be more information in the error message

@DerekO i edited and added the error message

saveAsTable function need hive metastore setuped correctly. The saveAsTable function writes in default as parquet when using default spark configs. In databricks delta is pre configured for you.

@SamuelDemir i wanted to ask what am I missing here I only installed spark and winutils am I missing some thing else

https://medium.com/@ibrahimadev77/installing-hadoop-spark-and-hive-locally-46caf5e41913
move to section D
